# .htaccess rewrites but doesn't capture

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file is simple:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?.*$ view.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^delete/([0-9]+)/?$ delete.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The first rule works perfectly. When I go to http://userless.net/123 the request is sent to view.php and I can access the id with `$_GET['id']`. The second rule rewrites fine too, it sends http://userless.net/delete/123 to delete.php, but the id is not captured!!! `$_GET['id']` is not even set. How can they be so similar and yet one work and the other fail? What am I missing?

Comment: How about this: ^delete/([0-9]+)/?.*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most like due to `MUltiViews` option turned on by default. You can turn it off by using this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+) view.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^delete/([0-9]+)/?$ delete.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```